# How many isohedral ways are there to stack $1\times 1\times 2$ blocks?

Tags: tiling

If I have blocks of size $1\times 1\times 2$ cubes, how many ways there are to stack them isohedrally in 3D space? I now have pretty robust system for solving this kind of problem in 2D, but 3D escapes me.

I presume that it could be solved by simply enumerating various kinds of planar layers composed of $1\times 2$ rectangles and/or $1\times 1$ squares and stacking them on top of each other, but that seems like it would have a lot of false solutions and couldn't be easily generalized for other shapes/geometries.

Comment: Stack them to make what shape? What size/shape of base?

Comment: Stack them to fill space.

Comment: Are you counting "ways" up to isometries of space? E.g., does stacking them all in vertical "columns" along the $z$-axis count as a distinct tiling from doing so along the $x$-axis?

Comment: No. Two arrangements that can be transformed into one another by isometry are considered the same.